# Is CSF overkill?

Tags: linux, web-server, csf

My server runs just my own sites (vBulletin forums - which are always patched with security fixes) and Rails sites using the latest version) so do I really need CSF? (http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html) Or is it unnecessary for this kind of server set-up?

I have already done the usual (disable SSH login, pub-key auth, very strong passwords everywhere else etc)

It was often recommended by users over at the cPanel forums - but I guess most of them are hosts there.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it is overkill. I run CSF on all my web servers. It does a great job at auto banning port scanners, failed logins and general hacking attempts. It updates its self on a regular bases and gives you a nice report on how secure your server is. Ontop of that it is super easy to manage what goes in and out of your server by port control etc.

It is impossible to be overkill with security not unless you are blocking your main ports, 80 :).

Comment: "impossible to be overkill with security" - strongly disagree. Adding gratuitous complexity can be catastrophic for security. That is not to say CSF might be a bad idea here! Just don't try to make your fireplace more safe by stuffing it full of safety matches.